# problem finding element on web page using RSelenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, findelement

I have been trying to get the element "Excel CSV" on a web page using the remDrv $ findElements in R software, but have not been able to achieve it. how could you call the element using the xpath, css, etc arguments?

i try:

```
library(RSelenium)


test_link="https://sinca.mma.gob.cl/cgi-bin/APUB-MMA/apub.htmlindico2.cgi?page=pageFrame&header=Talagante&macropath=./RM/D28/Cal/PM25&macro=PM25.horario.horario&from=080522&to=210909&"
    
    rD <- rsDriver(port=4446L, browser = "firefox", chromever = "92.0.4515.107") # runs a chrome browser, wait for necessary files to download
    remDrv <- rD$client
    #remDrv$open(silent = TRUE)
    url<-test_link
    remDrv$navigate(url)
    
    remDrv$findElements(using = "xpath", "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/label/span[3]/a")
```

link: https://sinca.mma.gob.cl/cgi-bin/APUB-MMA/apub.htmlindico2.cgi?page=pageFrame&header=Talagante&macropath=./RM/D28/Cal/PM25&macro=PM25.horario.horario&from=080522&to=210909&

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added more information